# KnockoutJs data-bind doesn't work with jquery click event on Internet Explorer(8-11)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I would like to do basic search event with KnockoutJS.

The button is bound with KnockoutJs to  filter records.
I am trying to trigger button's click event when user click enter button.It is working on Chrome and Firfox well.It also works on IE if **I click button manually.**

Problem is when I press enter key on keyboard, it doesn't filter(pass data to viewModel) on IE.I tracked  my viewModel. I see that if i press enter key it send previous data to viewModel,like:

1. Text Box Input value:30 -> click event triggered -> data on the viewmodel: null
2. Text Box Input value:20  -> click event triggered -> data on the viewmodel: 30(previous data)
3. Text Box Input value:10  -> click event triggered -> data on the viewmodel: 20(previous data)

```
     <button type="button" id="btnSearch" data-bind="click: filter" , class="btn btn-              primary btn-large" ></i>Filter</button>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtSearchText").keyup(function (event) {
        var evt = event || window.event;

        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(evt.keyCode);
            $("#btnSearch").click();


        }
    });

});
```

**MyViewModel:**

```
var ListCasesViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

self.selectedStartDate = ko.observable(null);
self.selectedEndDate = ko.observable(new Date());
self.selectedSearchKey = ko.observable("");
self.selectedStatuses = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedHospitals = ko.observableArray();

// methods...
this.init = function () {
    self.selectedEndDate(new Date());
    self.filter();

}

this.filter = function () {

    // get filter control values
    var startDate = self.selectedStartDate(); // dtStart.value();
    var endDate = self.selectedEndDate(); //dtEnd.value();
    var searchText = self.selectedSearchKey(); //txtSearchText.val();
    var lstStatus = $("#lstStatus").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var lstHospital = $("#lstHospitals").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var status = lstStatus.value().toString();
    var hospitalIDs = lstHospital.value().toString();


    // prepare filters
    $filter = new Array();

    if (startDate != undefined)
        $filter.push({ field: "startDate", operator: "eq", value: startDate });

    if (endDate != undefined)
        $filter.push({ field: "endDate", operator: "eq", value: endDate });

    if (status != undefined)
        $filter.push({ field: "caseStatus", operator: "eq", value: status });

    if (hospitalIDs != undefined)
        $filter.push({ field: "hospitalIDs", operator: "eq", value: hospitalIDs });

    if (searchText != undefined)
        $filter.push({ field: "searchText", operator: "eq", value: searchText });


    var list = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    list.dataSource.filter($filter);

}};
```

Comment: Does the keyup event get fired when you press Enter in IE? Which Jquery version are you using?

Comment: Yes ,keyup event is fired and i can see the value of keycode on popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the valueUpdate binding to your searchText input:

```
<input id="txtSearchText" type="text" data-bind="value:selectedSearchKey,valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"/>
```

This forces knockout to update the value of the observable as soon as a user types a letter.

[Knockout "value" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)

Comment: Worked.
Thank you so much,was trying to fix this problem for hours.But, I dont understand why I need to add valueUpdate property as it was working on chrome and firefox without it.

Comment: You're welcome, good to hear it's working.  I think it's just the way the different browsers update the underlying value; so attaching to the "keydown" event, gets round the fact that chrome/ff update the underlying dom element value on enter and ie doesn't.  Sorry I can't be more specific.